# Adding second join condition increases query time exponentially

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

So, I'm using Redshift (which is based on postgres). Unfortunately, I can't share my data (for reasons that will be obvious), but it's more of a conceptual question anyway. I will, of course, share my code.

This query returns virtually instantly:

```
select
    count(*)
from
    table_one as c
inner join
    table_two as z
on
    regexp_replace(c.telephone_number, '[^0-9]', '') = regexp_replace(z.affected_phone_number, '[^0-9]', '');
```

But this one will run for hours:

```
select
    count(*)
from
    table_one as c
inner join
    table_two as z
on
    regexp_replace(c.telephone_number, '[^0-9]', '') = regexp_replace(z.affected_phone_number, '[^0-9]', '')
    or c.email = z.requester_email;
```

Why does adding a second join condition with `or` cause this problem?

(I can get around this issue using a `union`, but I'm interested in learning here...)

Ran an `explain` if that helps...

Query plan for problem query:

```
QUERY PLAN
XN Aggregate  (cost=159728183882.77..159728183882.77 rows=1 width=0)
  ->  XN Nested Loop DS_BCAST_INNER  (cost=0.00..159726036322.85 rows=859023969 width=0)
        Join Filter: ((regexp_replace(("inner".telephone_number)::text, '[^0-9]'::text, ''::text, 1) = regexp_replace(("outer".affected_phone_number)::text, '[^0-9]'::text, ''::text, 1)) OR (("inner".email)::text = ("outer".requester_email)::text))
        ->  XN Seq Scan on table_two z  (cost=0.00..4447.40 rows=444740 width=36)
        ->  XN Seq Scan on table_one c  (cost=0.00..3853.89 rows=385389 width=32)
----- Nested Loop Join in the query plan - review the join predicates to avoid Cartesian products -----
```

Query plan for non-problem query:

```
QUERY PLAN
XN Aggregate  (cost=62358556140.01..62358556140.01 rows=1 width=0)
  ->  XN Hash Join DS_BCAST_INNER  (cost=4817.36..62356413666.21 rows=856989520 width=0)
        Hash Cond: (regexp_replace(("outer".affected_phone_number)::text, '[^0-9]'::text, ''::text, 1) = regexp_replace(("inner".telephone_number)::text, '[^0-9]'::text, ''::text, 1))
        ->  XN Seq Scan on table_two z  (cost=0.00..4447.40 rows=444740 width=12)
        ->  XN Hash  (cost=3853.89..3853.89 rows=385389 width=8)
              ->  XN Seq Scan on table_one c  (cost=0.00..3853.89 rows=385389 width=8)
```

Comment: what indexes does your "table_two" have.. it would probably help to have a composite index on ( requester_email, affected_phone_number )

Comment: You should add table definitions to the question as well. Redshift being an MPP database, physical design is of utmost importance.

Comment: `DS_BCAST_INNER:
A copy of the entire inner table is broadcast to all the compute nodes`.  All the network traffic plus a nested loop join. No wonder why it is exponentially slower

Answer (score 1):

We can only guess why it is slow without access to the database.

Guessing is not an appropriate tool for performance optimization.

Use the [EXPLAIN](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-explain.html) statement to see how postgres actually processes the two statements.

Comment: Explain information added... Obviously, the nested loop join is the problem, but I'm looking for a theoretical explanation of why the query is causing a nested loop join and if there's a way to fix it other than going with `union`...

Answer (score 1):

Are you using `sortkey` in your table schema?

If not, or if not on the appropriate fields the data will be sorted in the nodes by its insert order. Which will cause the loop that you are talking about.

Instead when specifying your table schema, make sure you include a `sortkey` that will be most often used, remember that you can have multiple `sortkeys`:

```
CREATE TABLE schemaex.a1.account_revenue (
    account_id varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    date date NOT NULL distkey,
    registration_date timestamp,
    revenue float(8),
    cost varchar(8),        
)
compound sortkey(account_id, date);
```

This should dramatically reduce execution time for joins and aggregations when using those fields in the sortkey as join keys and conditions respectively.

[Best Practices Sort Key](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_best-practices-sort-key.html)